# Imagine a world

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> Imagine a world that you can ask questions about a piece of program, and have tools that answer
>   the questions automatically and efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagine a world **where** you can ask questions about a piece of **a** program, and have tools that answer the questions automatically and efficiently.

*world* is a place so *where* is a better choice than *that*.

Also *those questions* might be better because it is referring to the questions in the first clause.

Comment: Good answer. Also, we have this tool already. It's called Stack Exchange :D